# Syntax for Extracting CGFloat out of NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary

Just wondering what the syntax would be to extract a `CGFloat` out of an `NSDictionary` like follows:

```
slider.minimumValue = [filterAttributes valueForKey:kCIAttributeSliderMin];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `NSDictionary` only holds objects. What kind of object would wrap a primitive like `CGFloat`? `NSNumber` would make sense. Now, since `CGFloat` is either a `float` or a `double`, you'll probably want to get the `double` value to preserve precision/range.

Therefore:

```
slider.minimumValue = [[filterAttributes valueForKey:kCIAttributeSliderMin] doubleValue];
```

Comment: Most likely you should be calling `objectForKey:`, not `valueForKey:`.

Answer (score 7):

You can only put OBJECTS into an NSDictionary (or NSARRAY).  CGFloat is a literal (just maps to a float), so you can't put it into or retrieve it from the dictionary.

Instead, wrap it as an NSNumber (when you add it to the dictionary), which is an object.

```
NSNumber *sliderMin = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:kCIAttributeSliderMin]
```

Or using the new syntax, you can just say `@kCIAttributeSliderMin` or `@(kCIAttributeSliderMin)` to autobox as an NSNumber.

To get the value back out, you'll retrieve the object as an `NSNumber` then say, `[myNumber floatVal]` to get the `NSFloat`.

Finally, you probably want to say "`objectForKey`" not "`valueForKey`".

*update* - sorry, in your example you're treating `kCIAttributeSliderMin` as a key, and I'm using it as the 'value'; but I think you get the point.  Store an NSNumber object; retrieve an NSNumber object.  Sorry for any confusion swapping that may have caused.

Comment: One note on this answer: `kCIAttributeSliderMin` is actually a `NSString*` that is defined as part of Apple's CIFilter code. So, @Dave is correct that you want to wrap `CGFloat`s as `NSNumber`s and use `objectForKey:` rather than `valueForKey:`, but getting the value referenced by `kCIAttributeSliderMin` will not require wrapping it is a number.

Comment: `floatVal` is not the name of a method that `NSNumber` responds to (it's `floatValue`). `NSFloat` is not a type (it's `CGFloat`). And you should be using `doubleValue` because `CGFloat` is a `double` on 64-bit systems.

Comment: yup, I just noticed that as well, updated my answer - and see you caught it in the comments - so hopefully that didn't confuse anyone.